# Как правильно преобразовать char в int?

Tags: java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class Main {
    static char[] list2 = {'+', '-', '*', '/'};
    private static Calculate calculate = new Calculate();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        while(true) {
            try {
                System.out.println("CALCULATOR");
                String num = reader.readLine();

                int a = (int) num.charAt(0);
                char PMMD = num.charAt(2);
                int b = (int) num.charAt(4);

                if (PMMD == list2[0]) {
                    System.out.println(calculate.getPlus(a, b));
                }
                if (PMMD == list2[1]) {
                    System.out.println(calculate.getMinus(a, b));
                }
                if (PMMD == list2[2]) {
                    System.out.println(calculate.getMulti(a, b));
                }
                if (PMMD == list2[3]) {
                    System.out.println(calculate.getDiv(a, b));
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    }
}

public class Calculate {
    private int a;
    private int b;

    public Calculate(int a, int b){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
    public Calculate(){

    }
    public int getPlus(int a, int b){
        return a + b;
    }
    public int getMinus(int a, int b){
        return a - b;
    }
    public int getMulti(int a, int b){
        return a * b;
    }
    public int getDiv(int a, int b){
        return a / b;
    }
}
```

`1 + 2` как это правильно считывать с консоли?

Answer (score 4):

Объясняю.

Код символа "1" - 49.

Код символа "2" - 50.

49 плюс 50 будет 99.

```
int a = Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(0)); // a будет 1
```

Comment: Спасибо я понял

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!!! решил

Comment: @ArmanAbdullin На здоровье. Успехов! Слева от ответа - знак "галочка".